# Document write gives strange output

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script to detect jQuery, if it doesn't exist then insert the Google CDN version and a local fallback (don't ask why... it's not my idea), the problem is when I try to do document.write I get a strange output

```
document.write("<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"js/jquery.v1.9.1.js\"><\/script>')</script>");
```

the output should come to:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.v1.9.1.js"></script>')</script>
```

but comes to:

```
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.v1.9.1.js"></script>"')"
```

can't figure out for the life of me whats wrong

Comment: That's because the `</script>` in the string matches the end of the beginning `<script>` element. See [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)

Comment: Why not do this instead: `if (!window.jQuery) document.write("<script src=\"js/jquery.v1.9.1.js\"></script>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what's happening is that when `document.write` prints out

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"js/jquery.v1.9.1.js\"></script>')</script>
```

that first `</script>` is being parsed into the actual end-of-script tag, even though it's inside of a string, resulting in something like

```
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"js/jquery.v1.9.1.js\">
</script>
')
</script>
```

The string is not ended (unterminated string literal) because its closing single quote is now outside of the script, and there is also a dangling end-of-script tag. To stop this from happening, you simply need to escape like crazy the script tags inside the string, especially in the string inside the string. Below is a working example.

```
document.write("<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"js/jquery.v1.9.1.js\"><\\\/script>')<\/script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
document.write("<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"js/jquery.v1.9.1.js\"/>')<\/script>");
```